# Log4j2 Rolled Files that are deleted are still open and disk space not freed

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6, log4j2

I recently migrated from log4j to log4j2 on my tomcat6 server. The problem is that my rolling files that are deleted are remaining open forever and hence the disk space is not being freed.
i used this command "sudo /usr/sbin/lsof | grep deleted" to check on the open deleted files. I don't seem to understand how to close those files without restarting the tomcat server. Some of these logs are being deleted by cron jobs. while a lot of them are being deleted via logrotate.

...

```
 <Appenders>
    <RollingRandomAccessFile name="requestAppender" fileName="${sys:catalina.home}/webapps/miscLogs/request.log"
                filePattern="${sys:catalina.home}/webapps/miscLogs/request.log.%i">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>
                    "%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss } %-5p %c %x -%m%n"
                </Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="3400MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="3"/>
</RollingRandomAccessFile>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
<logger additivity="false" name="requestLogger" level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="requestAppender"/>
        </logger>
</Loggers>
```

...

The problem is with the files that have already been rolled. In this case the problem is with request.log.3. It's being deleted by a cron (no logrotate) but it's still not giving up disk space and is held open by the tomcat server on which the whole program is running.

the output of lsof is below..

java       6393          root  160u      REG                8,1  3565160049    5525509 /opt/tomcat/webapps/miscLogs/request.log.1 (deleted)

here the java process is the tomcat 6 server which is still holding the file open.

Comment: What do you mean "rolling files that are deleted"? Log4j does not currently have a delete function for rolled-over files. I checked the source, but log4j is closing the stream (RollingFileManager line 171)...

Comment: Please provide more detail. How are log files deleted? By cron? Logrotate? Please show the exact command. Also please provide your log4j2.xml config. Are you using RandomAccessFileAppender?

Comment: Some of these logs are being deleted by cron jobs. while a lot of them are being deleted via logrotate.

Comment: There is a known problem with RandomAccessFileAppender and logrotate: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-354; better use RollingRandomAccessFileAppender....

Comment: Even if i delete a rolled over file manually still the disk space is not freed and it is being displayed as an open deleted file.

Comment: Thanks. Using rollingRandomAccessFile appender worked

Comment: Great, I'll put that in the form of an answer then.

Answer (score 0):

There is a known problem with RandomAccessFileAppender and logrotate: http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-354; the Log4j team recommends using RollingRandomAccessFileAppender instead.

Comment: hey there still seems to be a problem with the files remaining open.I am sharing the xml config.

Comment: Did you switch off logrotate?

Comment: yes i did eventually. Now the rotation is being done by log4j only. But some rolled over logs are being deleted by a cron job. A subset of those deleted logs are still held open by the tomcat server.

Answer (score 0):

```
DefaultRollOverStrategy:
      max: 3
      Delete:
        basePath: "${sys:logDir}/archive"
        IfLastModified:
          age: "5d"
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.