# Log4j2 rolling leaves file handles open

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

When Log4j2 rolls my log files it leaves some of them open I can see that in lsof:

```
java       6684      root  609u      REG        8,3      5791     142217 /jboss/server/all/log/info.log.2015-01-30 12:48-2.log (deleted)
java       6684      root  613r      REG        8,3      2917     140533 /jboss/server/all/log/info.log.2015-01-30 12:45-1.log (deleted)
java       6684      root  621u      REG        8,3     78090     140536 /jboss/server/all/log/service.manager.log.2015-01-30 12:46-1.log (deleted)
java       6684      root  622u      REG        8,3       309     140541 /jboss/server/all/log/info.log.2015-01-30 12:46-1.log (deleted)
java       6684      root  623u      REG        8,3       309     140539 /jboss/server/all/log/node.log.2015-01-30 12:46-1.log (deleted)
java       6684      root  644r      REG        8,3    126606     140228 /jboss/server/all/log/info.log.2015-01-30 12:44-1.log (deleted)
java       6684      root  648r      REG        8,3     70026     135612 /jboss/server/all/log/node.log.2015-01-30 12:44-1.log (deleted)
java       6684      root  649r      REG        8,3    126606     140202 /jboss/server/all/log/service.manager.log.2015-01-30 12:44-1.log (deleted)
java       6684      root  652r      REG        8,3      2917     140530 /jboss/server/all/log/node.log.2015-01-30 12:45-1.log (deleted)
java       6684      root  653r      REG        8,3    113366     140526 /jboss/server/all/log/service.manager.log.2015-01-30 12:45-1.log (deleted)
java       6684      root  654u      REG        8,3       322     140543 /jboss/server/all/log/service.manager.log.2015-01-30 12:47-1.log (deleted)
```

Here is one of my configuration files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="trace">
    <Appenders>
        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="PCI" fileName="${sys:jboss.server.home.dir}}/log/mycast.pci.log"
                     filePattern="${sys:jboss.server.home.dir}}/log/mycast.pci.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}-%i.log.gz">
            <param name="Threshold" value="trace" />
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d %-5p [%c{1}] (%t) {%x}: %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="32 MB"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.abc" level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="PCI" />
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I tried RollingRandomAccessFileAppender as suggested in: [Log4j2 Rolled Files that are deleted are still open and disk space not freed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27855869/log4j2-rolled-files-that-are-deleted-are-still-open-and-disk-space-not-freed) but I got:

```
RollingRandomAccessFileAppender: CLASS_NOT_FOUND
```

Is there a way to tell Log4j2 to close files before rolling or after some time not being used? Should I use some other roller?

Thanks

Comment: Does the RollingFile appender have the same problem? This may be an alternative.

Comment: Yes, I tried it and RollingFile also leaves them open.

Answer (score 0):

This looks strange:  The paths don't seem to match exactly:

/jboss/server/all/log/info.log.2015-01-30 12:48-2.log (deleted)

fileName="${sys:jboss.server.home.dir}}/log/mycast.pci.log"
                     filePattern="${sys:jboss.server.home.dir}}/log/mycast.pci.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}-%i.log.gz">

The rollover path has a date but ends in ".gz", where the open file handles don't end in ".gz".

Have you tried removing the space in the filePattern?

Comment: I have multiple log4j2 configuration files, I pasted the shortest one so paths may not match, but they work the same. Removing the space does not work. The reason why opened file does not end in ".gz" is (I think) log file is opened before rolling so log4j2 keeps it's handle open and when it is renamed it is considered as deleted.